# how convert images into uint8 without loss of information, to export them as video in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an Image collection, I want to export them as a video file to my drive. Documentation says I need to convert my Images into uint8 RGB format for this matter [doc link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting#exporting-video). problem is when I convert them to uint8 almost all values get clipped into 255, hence the whole scene is flat bright white!
it is of course impossible to do it lossless but, how should I do this without much loss of information so the video looks good at least?

Answer (score 0):

this works but not very good quality obviously:

```
var to_uint8 = function(img){
    return img.toDouble().divide(3000).multiply(255).uint8();
    };
my_collection = my_collection.map(to_uint8);
```